# Не могу установить pyinstaller, испробовал всё, но в итоге выдаёт эту ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\днс\appdata\local\programs\pyt
hon\python37-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\днс\appdata\local\programs\python\python37
-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_bu
ild_wheel 'C:\Users\BD1F~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5o3wqo8g':
    ERROR: running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\BD1F~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4w77ap2p\pyinstaller
\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\BD1F~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4w77ap2p\pyinstaller\
pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\BD1F~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4
w77ap2p\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt

writing entry points to C:\Users\BD1F~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4w77a
p2p\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\BD1F~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4w77a
p2p\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\BD1F~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4w
77ap2p\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\BD1F~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4w77ap
2p\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\BD1F~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4w77ap
2p\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in positio
n 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory
 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching 'news\_template.rst'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\BD1F~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4w77ap
2p\pyinstaller\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\BD1F~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4w77ap2p\pyinstalle
r\pip-wheel-metadata\PyInstaller.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\днс\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.e
xe' 'c:\users\днс\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pi
p\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\BD1F
~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5o3wqo8g'" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\BD1F~1\
AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4w77ap2p\pyinstaller
```

Comment: `pip install --upgrade wheel` делал?

Comment: Русские буквы в пути. Вообще не хорошо.

Comment: Проблема в кириллических символах в пути, куда происходит установка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переустановил Python в папку без русских символов и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Главное правило в установке чего-либо - это не устанавливать что-либо в папки с кириллицей.

Comment: Нет такого правила. Бывает ПО, которое может не учитывать возможности существования путей, но большинство программ сейчас нормально себя чувствуют при установке по пути с любыми символами.

Answer (score 0):

При установке ОС надо выбирать имя пользователя с только латинскими буквами. Тогда путь

```
c:\users\днс\appdata\
```

будет

```
c:\users\moyoimya\appdata\
```

и всe будет работать.

Comment: Почему комментарий? Разве отвечать может только автор вопроса?

Comment: Изначально вы обращались конкретно к автору другого ответа. Теперь это как бы ответ, но ваше решение очень не оптимально - оно предполагает переустановку системы, в то время как проблема решается просто переустановкой Python в другую папку.